# Can I use a PositiveSSL Wildcard cert for *.blah.foo.com? (all fourth-level domains)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'd like to secure many servers such as `test.blah.foo.com`, `dev.blah.foo.com`, etc.

If I buy a Comodo PositiveSSL Wildcard Certificate can I secure `*.blah.foo.com` ?

(`blah` and `foo` and `com` being placeholders for my own 3rd, 2nd, and top-level domain names, of course)

I'm not sure if this question is specific to Comodo's PositiveSSL certs or wildcard certs in general.

This is a crosspost of http://community.namecheap.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=4760

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this a few months back.  You can buy a certificate for whatever you want!  However a few things to keep in mind...

You cannot buy a wildcart cert for your third level domain and have it protect your fourth level domains, you have to secure the domains at each level of the domain name tree.  In general the SSL providers won't restrict how many levels you can have though.

We had a wildcard cert for our third level domain name, something like *.us.mydomain.com which allowed us to secure our US resources, but we also needed one for our Polish resources so another cert for *.pl.mydomain.com was required.

Some of the providers may limit to what depth you can go though, but the browsers should all support it.

Comment: Thanks! [Confirmed by Namecheap staff](https://community.namecheap.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=4760&sid=b9018c8fe50cf54e79179dd66e3e4d16&p=17770#p17770). Note that they say they do not support wildcard SSL certs for fifth-level domains (*.bar.blah.foo.com).

Comment: @AdamMonsen Good to know.  I imagine the depth supported may vary by provider as well.

Comment: @AdamMonsen Dead link.

Comment: @ErikKralj bummer, they must have moved their forums. :(